# Java Compiler error puzzler: "inner classes cannot have static declarations" - except for simple types

Tags: java, compiler-construction, compiler-errors

While coding, I have encountered a strange Java Compiler behaviour.

When compiling the class (source below), the compiler emits an error ("`inner classes cannot have static declarations`") on the NULL class variable. This is as expected!

However, no error is generated on the ZERO class variable. This I don't understand!

Why this difference, which seems to allow static declarations of simple types, but not Objects, in inner classes.

> (javac -version: 1.6.0_24)

```
public class Outer {
    public static final Runnable HELLO = new Runnable() {
        // No compiler error
        public static final int ZERO = 0;

        // Causes compiler error: "inner classes cannot have static declarations"
        public static final Object NULL = null;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Hello " + ZERO + NULL);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I think it's because the priomitive variable will be treated as a constant and compiled *inline*, whereas the `Object` reference will not. I remember seeing something about how the compiler treats constants with `null` reference in this YouTube video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V1vQf4qyMXg&t=68m1s

Comment: Whether it is a null reference, or a "new Object()" reference makes no difference, both cause a compiler error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that inner classes cannot have a static initialiser block which is required to initialise non-trivial constants and non-constants.

Comment: +1; One could argue that the error message is not very explicit. The first declaration is also `static`.

Comment: Also don't know why an inner class can't have a static initialiser block. :|

Comment: If inner classes cannot have a static initializer block, why can you initialize a static simple type class variable?
Which part of the Java Language Specification allows one but not the other.
I actually think that the real problem is that no compiler error is generated for the simple type class variable (static field).

Comment: Simple primitive field have a default value in the byte code, they don't need a static block to initialise them.

Comment: OK, accepted.
So (as maba correctly stated), the compiler error `"inner classes cannot have static declarations"` is strictly speaking wrong (or misleading, at best), since inner classes **are** allowed to have static declarations. The error should have been something like `"inner classes cannot have static initializer code"`, right?